# How to not add reference to certain parts of object

Tags: c#, json, web, asp.net-web-api

I've made an object (Foo) which has a parameter (Foo2Ref) whose reference needs to be set to another object (Foo2). However, I want to hide/remove certain elements of Foo2 when adding its reference to Foo2Ref (**Foo gets requested by a web api call and I don't want certain elements of Foo2 visible to the client**). All elements within Foo2 are read only, so I can't just say something like Foo.Foo2Ref.x = null.

Just to clarify a bit more:

```
public class Foo
{
    public string blah {get; set;}
    ...
    public Foo2 Foo2Ref {get; set;}
    ...
}

public class Foo2
{
    public x {get;}
    public y {get;}
    public z {get;}
}
```

So, in the example above, I want to hide "x" within Foo2 from the client, but y and z should be sent back. Is there a way to do this? I can't do something like

```
Foo2Ref.x = null
```

since x is read only.

Comment: How are you returning this to the client? Is the object being serialized to JSON/XML or are you returning it as a complex object (e.g. in a SOAP contract)?

Comment: @PoweredByOrange It's being serialized to JSON

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit 1:**

If you cannot modify the class, you might consider making a wrapper class.

```
public class Foo2Wrapper
{
    private Foo2 _obj;

    public Foo2Wrapper(Foo2 obj)
    {
        _obj = obj;
    }
    public int x { get { return _obj.x; } }
}
```

Then, only expose that class.

```
public class Foo
{
    public Foo2Wrapper Foo2Ref {get; set;}
}
```

You could alternatively (if you still needed access to the object's internal properties) do it this way:

```
public class Foo
{
    public Foo(Foo2 obj)
    {
        _myFoo2 = obj;
    }

    internal Foo2 _myFoo2;
    public Foo2Wrapper Foo2Ref { get { return new Foo2Wrapper(_myFoo2); } }
}
```

If it's a frequently requested object, you can create the Foo2Wrapper in the constructor and just store that alongside your original object.

**Original answer**

If you have control of the code, you can create an interface. If you don't want the client casting the interface back to Foo2, you might make it `internal` as shown below.

```
public class Foo
{
    public string blah { get; set; }
    public IFoo2 Foo2Ref { get; set; }
}

internal class Foo2 : IFoo2
{
    public int x { get; }
    public int y { get; }
    public int z { get; }
}

public interface IFoo2
{
    int x { get; }
}
```

With this setup, the client can only access `Foo2.x`.

Comment: You will need to create a wrapper class, then. (I can't seem to get a code block to show up here.)

Comment: Hmm, alright. Could you edit your answer and add in a sample code block maybe?

Comment: I've added a solution that does not require you to have access to the code of Foo2.